# SSRS Report parameters - Textarea instead of Textbox

Tags: ssrs-2008

Does anyone know if its possible to create a parameter in SSRS that will display a Textarea instead of a Texbox and let the user type in a few paragraphs of text, including carriage returns?

I've a requirement to create a report that will end up as data with a cover letter. A section of the cover letter needs to have a block of text, which the user can specify when setting the parameters.

I can create a 'text' parameter which displays a Textbox, but that does not accept carriage returns. I have tried to copy and paste text from Word, but then it only takes the first line of text.

Has anyone got any suggestions? So far I've not managed to find any solutions online.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Right click on your textbox, go to properties. Under Format tab there is check box Can Increase to accommodate contents. Is that checked for your textbox?

Comment: It's not a textbox in the report body that I need to change, it's the textbox that appears in the parameter toolbar that let you enter a text parameter. I need to be able to enter multiple paragraphs of text.

Comment: Please attach screenshot.

Comment: Sorry problem solved,

I changed the text parameter so that it could accept multiple values. Then on the textbox that displayed the text on the letter I changed the expression to read: =Join(Parameters!FreeText.Value, vbcrlf)
Sorted. I'll put that down as an answer once the 8 hours is up.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry problem solved,

I changed the text parameter so that it could accept multiple values. Then on the textbox that displayed the text on the letter I changed the expression to read:

```
=Join(Parameters!FreeText.Value, vbcrlf)
```

Sorted.